# Angular 2: How to autherization header to http.get request?

Tags: angularjs, spring, angular, spring-boot, cors

I am totally confused with what is going on here. 
Spring Boot backend accepts requests sent with  `X-Auth-Token` header values. It works fine if I send the request from ARC client.
GET request from angular code is not going with `X-Auth-Token` request header.

Angular code:

```
getCandidatesByUserId(userId: number): Observable<Candidate[]> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/json' });
    headers.append('X-AUTH-TOKEN', this.token );
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    console.log('Found token is '+ headers.get('X-AUTH-TOKEN'));
    return this.http.get(this.url+userId+'/candidates', {
      headers: headers
    })
      .map((response: Response) => <Candidate[]> response.json())
      .do(data => console.log('All: '+ JSON.stringify(data)))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Spring Boot code:

```
public final void doFilter(final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse res, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        // without this header jquery.ajax calls returns 401 even after
        // successful login and SSESSIONID being succesfully stored.
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-AUTH-TOKEN, Content-Type");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-AUTH-TOKEN, Content-Type");

        final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>"+request.getRequestURL()+" X-Auth-Token::"+ request.getHeader("X-AUTH-TOKEN"));

        if (request.getMethod() != "OPTIONS") {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        } else {
            //
        }
    }
```

Last `sysout`statement always prints null value for X-Auth-Token header.

Error:
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403`

Comment: what are the errors that your are getting in the console?

Comment: @Aravind updated with error message

Comment: are you sure that the token from angular has a value.

Comment: Yes. console log on line 5 prints the value.

Comment: update the post with the screenshot of the console network call along with the request and response message